# Hide CMD after opening

Tags: cmd

Does anybody know how to hide a console window (cmd), by just typing something into the console (not usbing VBS, batch-file or whatever), just using the cmd?

Is there  a way to minimize it but still be able to type something?

Also heard of a possibility to just move the window out of your monitors size, does this work and if yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start it minimized with `start /min` or start a new cmd minimized and close the old cmd `start /min && exit` but you loose the focus, you can't type commands in the minimized cmd, you need to klick it and bring it to front. You could execute a bat file with your commands (to execute them "invisible") `start /min cmd.exe /C mybat.bat && exit`

For "windows+r" (run) you can use: `cmd.exe /C "start /min cmd"`

Comment: Where do I have to type start /min ? Just in the run window (windows+r)? Don't want to use a batch file or similar

Comment: cmd.exe /C "start /min cmd"   for windows+r

Comment: Can I combine both (directly running commands) and opening it with "windows+r", so having it opened automatically exectuing "echo test" or something, you know what I mean? I tried `cmd.exe /C "start /min cmd" /C "echo test"`this, but it immediately closes cmd, so I can't see if it worked

Comment: Use the /K flag for cmd: cmd.exe /C "start /min cmd /K echo test" the /C flag closes the new cmd the /K flag keeps the new cmd open